# Кавычки в innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

Капец запутался совсем с ними

```
   <div class="delete_post"  onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML = 
    '<div id="post_del49294537_597" class="dld" style="display: block">+"Сообщение удалено."+ <a> +"Восстановить"+ </a><a> +"Это спам"+ </a></div>'
   "></div>
```

В общем надо вставить

```
    <div id="post_del49294537_597" class="dld" style="display: block">
        Сообщение удалено.
       <a>Восстановить</a>
       <a>Это спам</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: ничего не понятно в этом месиве пробелов и букв)

Comment: @thunder отчасти ответ набум в 50% прокатывает :D

Comment: что за диво геморой)

Comment: Это вы для hashcode? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
innerHTML = '<div id="post_del49294537_597" class="dld" style="display: block">\
Сообщение удалено.\
<a>Восстановить</a>\
<a>Это спам</a>\
</div>';
```

Поправочка:

```
<script>
    function removeMess(th) {
        th.parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML = '<div id="'+th.getAttribute('data')+'" class="dld" style="display: block">\
            Сообщение удалено.\
            <a>Восстановить</a>\
            <a>Это спам</a>\
            </div>';
    }
</script>

<div data='post_del49294537_597' class="delete_post" onclick="removeMess(this)"></div>
```

Comment: не забудь, что оно через `onlick` делается :) что конечно не айс, но видимо так надо

Comment: @thunder не понял, ты о чем именно? 

а, вижу.

Comment: В этом и была проблема, что надо было через функцию в скрипте делать, а не как я

Comment: O_o неожиданно! а где это в вопросе написано???

Comment: я имел ввиду, что если бы я сразу по-пробывал через функцию, а не в <body> то такого бы не было

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="delete_post"  onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML = 
    '<div id=\"post_del49294537_597\" class=\"dld\" style=\"display: block\">+\"Сообщение удалено.\"+ <a> +\"Восстановить\"+ </a><a> +\"Это спам\"+ </a></div>'
   "></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

ну так заэкранируйте их, в чем проблема?

```
<div class="delete_post"  onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML = 
    '<div id=\"post_del49294537_597\" class=\"dld\" style=\"display: block\">Сообщение удалено.<br/><a>Восстановить</a><br/><a>Это спам</a></div>'
   "></div>
```

хотя не понятно что хза `+"Сообщение удалено"+` =)

Comment: Это в ВК так, я не когда не обертываю текст в divом, обычно <p>